# Filehelpers - Export with double quotes around each field

Tags: .net, filehelpers

This is one of those things that I'm sure is really easy, but I can't seem to work it out!

Using FileHelpers, how do I make sure that every field in my export contains double quotes? I'm guessing there's an attribute I can put over each field I want to have double quotes around it but I can't see where it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorate your fields with [`FieldQuotedAttribute`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FieldQuotedAttribute.html) using one of [the available constructors](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FieldQuotedAttributeConstructor.html) that allow you to specify a `QuoteMode`. For example:

```
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
```